# Store csv data as rows or columns in view of the needed processing?

Tags: design, c++, algorithms, data-structures, array

Assume I have some data a csv-Files like

```
ObjectName, PropertyA, PropertyB, PropertyC
"Name1", 3, 1, 4
"Name2", 1, 5, 9
"Name3", 2, 6, 5
...
```

and a typical question I want to answer would be

> For which Object is PropertyX maximal?

I have two approaches for this and would be thankful for some Input.

---

**Approach 1**

I define a class like

```
struct Object {
    std::String name;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Store the data in a class like

```
class ObjectCollection {
    std::vector<Object> collection;
}
```

And provide two functions

```
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfA()
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfB()
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfC()
```

Now these Functions would essentially be the same and look like

```
size_t maxIndex = -1;
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for (size_t i = 0; i < collection.size(); ++i) {
    if (collection[i].a > max) {
        maxIndex = i;
        max = collection[i].a; 
    }
}
return maxIndex;
```

It bothers me that I would have to write and maintain the same code twice.

---

**Approach 2**

Store the data in a class like

```
class ObjectCollection {
    std::vector<String> names;
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    std::vector<int> c;
}
```

Then I could provide methods like

```
const std::vector<int>& ObjectCollection::getA() const;
const std::vector<int>& ObjectCollection::getB() const;
const std::vector<int>& ObjectCollection::getC() const;
```

And use a single function to find the maximum which I have to call as

```
getMaxIndex( collection.getA() );
```

where `size_t getMaxIndex(const std::vector<int>&)` would be essentially the same as in approach 1.

---

I think I prefer the second approach, but it bothers me that in this case there is no class representing a single Object.

Is it weird/bad design to store the data as in the second approach? Is there another smart approach I didn't think about?

By the way, I am more concerned with the choice between these two approaches than the fact that I should probably use `std::max_element` to find the index.

Comment: Your only criticism of approach 1 is “It bothers me that I would have to write and maintain the same code twice”, yet you exclude template functions such as `std::max_element()` which address exactly this problem? Especially the overload that takes a custom comparator. Don't contort your design when easy solutions are available in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another smart approach I didn't think about?

If your properties are of the same type and behave similar, why not address them by an index?

```
enum PropIndex{PropertyA=0, PropertyB=1, PropertyC=2};

struct Object {
    std::String name;
    std::vector<int> property(3); // use PropIndex to access the value you want

    // if that helps for convenience, you can also add getters and setters like this one 
    int getA(){ return property(PropertyA); }
    //  ... but then you should consider to make the public members 
    //  ... all private, and provide proper public getters/setter for all of them
};
```

Now you need to implement your maximum function only once (with an additional parameter which Property you want).

Comment: +1..  was wondering, though, if there's exactly three wouldn't an array be just as effective, and simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 is unarguably the better design - it represents the "reality" of the data much better, which will make it much easier for future developers to understand.

Answer (score 1):

So have both.  There's no written rule that you must stick with the model you've chosen.  You keep `ObjectCollection` class and have a method like `getObject(int index)` return a `Object` instance for all values of that row.

Your `getObject` method would simply have to lookup the values laterally across all vectors and put their references in `Object` class.

If you think you might need to call this method a lot, consider representing the data in *both* ways.  Yes, that is to say, make `ObjectCollection` class hold vector column data as well as a single vector with `Object` instances.  Obviously you'd be using up more memory, but this is the old memory-performance tradeoff.  If you feel performance is more important here, don't hestitate to do it this way!

Answer (score 1):

#### Domain goes first !

The design should aim at correctly representing the domain, before going into tactical considerations.

So approach 1 is the way to go. It perfectly reflects the real structure of your data, and it enforces separation of concerns between `Collection` and `Object`.  For example, you could easily change the collection's container (e.g. replacing array with a map or a linked list) or the objects's properties (e.g. `collection[i].average_abc()`).

#### DRY using pointers to member

You can write a private helper function that would work with a pointer to member instead of a being bound to a specific member:

```
class ObjectCollection {
    size_t getMaxIndexOf(int Object::* o); // private helper function 
public:
    std::vector<Object> collection;
    size_t getMaxIndexOfA();
    size_t getMaxIndexOfB();
    size_t getMaxIndexOfC();
};
```

A [pointer to member](http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/pointer-to-members.php) is a very special beast:  it is relative to an object, so that you can use the same pointer and combine it with all items of your collection:

```
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOf(int Object::* o) {
    size_t maxIndex = -1;
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < collection.size(); ++i) {
       if (collection[i].*o > max) {  // <---- use of the pointer to member
           maxIndex = i;
           max = collection[i].*o;  // <---- use of the pointer to member
       }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

You can then reuse your helper function as follows:

```
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfA() {
    return getMaxIndexOf(&Object::a);
}
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfB() {
    return getMaxIndexOf(&Object::b);
}
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfC() {
    return getMaxIndexOf(&Object::c);
}
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/kqLegl)

#### DRY using standard algorithms

As suggested by [Amon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/60357/amon) in the comments, you could just use [`std::max_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element):

```
size_t ObjectCollection::getMaxIndexOfA() {
    auto it = std::max_element(collection.begin(), collection.end(), 
                            [](auto &o1, auto &o2){ return o1.a<o2.a; });
    return std::distance(collection.begin(), it);
}
```

This standard algorithm returns an iterator, but as shown, you can convert it back to an index.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/XcQWZW)